# Bean dependency injection in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependencies, code-injection

I have four projects project a , project b , project c, project d.

I want to use some manager class of project c in b , but can't access it directly. and have to do it through project a .

If i move my manager class from project c  to project a , then i have some others managers called which i dont have access in project a.

I am using spring to configure these beans. Is there a way in spring to inject dependency such that i have direct access to manager class of project c in b.

How to process this ?

Answer (score 1):

Better to have some sort of **main** project, that have *master-context* where all your beans will be defined. That way you can get access to the bean from any point.